# I have been trying to write code for my ultrasonic detector, and i execute it with no errors, but it doesn't do anything

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```
from gpiozero import InputDevice, OutputDevice
from time import sleep, time

trig = OutputDevice(4)
echo= InputDevice(17)

sleep (2)

def get_pulse_time():
    trig.on()
    sleep(0.00001)
    trig.off()

    while echo.is_active == False:
            pulse_start = time()

    while echo.is_active == True:
            pulse_end = time()
    
    sleep(0.06)

    return pulse_end - pulse_start

print(get_pulse_time())
```

Comment: You really need to put a limit on how long those `while` loops will run, so that they don't hang if no echo is ever received.  Also, I'm not sure that 10 microseconds is long enough of a pulse to be reliably detected.

Comment: How do I do that